# AWS: Deploying Web Servers in a private subnet behind an internet facing ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, subnet

From a cost optimization perspective, are there any benefits in deploying web servers in private subnets rather than in public subnets? (behind an Internet-facing ALB)

What would be the pros and cons for the two approaches?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting your web-servers in private subnets will probably be more expensive (depends on exactly what the servers do) then putting them in public. The reason is that in private subnet they will **not have access** to the internet nor any AWS services.

Thus if they require the use of some external API or access to some AWS services you will need to use NAT gateway and/or VPC endpoints which are **not free** (except endpoints to S3 and DynamoDB).

But keeping everything in a public subnet is a **security risk** and many prefer to keep the servers in private subnets to follow good practices and be more secure then cheap.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer - No**

One case where it will be a bit more expensive:

If you need to access public internet from your server, you will need to pay some money for either **NAT gateway, or NAT instance.** [NAT gateway vs NAT instance](https://dzone.com/articles/nat-instance-vs-nat-gateway).

**When to use  Public subnet**

1. You are not planning on using any ALB, or autoscaling, and would like to attach Elastic IP directly to your single instance.
2. You would like to have access to the internet from your ec2, and not pay for NAT

**When to use Private subnet**

1. If you are planning to use ALB: You should always have 1 entry point to your application, let it be through publicly faced ALB, and don't risk, by allowing direct public access to your service. For ssh or other direct connection, you can setup [bastion host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastion_host)
2. Any service that should not be accessible from the public internet should be better placed in a private subnet and communicate with other services through a private network, which is faster and cheaper, also, when communicating inside vpc, you can set up good security groups.